# Setting Attributes in Webby Layouts

Tags: ruby, webby

I'm working with [Webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org) and am looking for some clarification.  Can I define attributes like `title` or `author` in my layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.  The layout has access to the page attributes rather than the other way.

The easiest way to do what you want is to populate the SITE.page_defaults hash in your site's Rakefile (probably build.rake).  Add something like the following:

```
SITE.page_defaults['title']             = "My awesome title"
SITE.page_defaults['author']            = "Shazbug"
SITE.page_defaults['is_mando_awesome']  = "very yes"
```

You can now access those hash members in your template:

```
Written by <%= @page.author %>
```

You can find more info about Webby's page default stuff on the Google Group, specifically here:

http://groups.google.com/group/webby-forum/browse_thread/thread/f3dc1f4187959634/c30d7883705f6218?lnk=gst&q=SITE#c30d7883705f6218

Answer (score 0):

[I've never used it but the tutorial here:](http://webby.rubyforge.org/tutorial/)

Makes it look like the answer to your question is "yes".  Specifically I'm looking under the "Making Changes" header on that page.

Comment: What you (and the tutorial) mention is valid for the content pages. It is not true for the layouts, however.